# multi user website in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I want to build a multi user website where my users register and their account is created.

After sign up the user gets a specific url to build his website. Like. Mysite.com/user1

Now the user can login to the control panel and publish his data. Eg he has created a faq page.

His faq page should be available like

Mysite.com/user1/faq

I've done everything but this faq page building does not work at all.

I check the user for existence in the DB and route to his page in the routes.php file
:any = home/loader/$1

And in loader.php I fetch the details and display his welcome page, for the faq page, I have created a function in the loader.php controller as
Faq()
And built a custom view for it but now when I try to access the page it only loads the welcome page.
I tried all methods but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at the Tutplus

[http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter--net-16330)

It explains how to work with wildcard routing in codeigniter

Comment: i tried but the end user website only displays the welcome page other urls are not opening instead they show the welcome page only